# Microsoft Word 2016 isn't respecting image placement in header & footer

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I'm working on a document in MW and I've placed in images to be used for the background in the footer. Formatted it so it was behind text (incase I wanted to place text on top of it later) and have also gone into the positioning settings and make it not act as a paragraph.

I escape out of the header/footer and start typing in my document. Then randomly the background image will move! It will eventually end up at the bottom of my page with only an inch of the top showing - but I haven't gone into the header/footer section to do this. This document is 5 pages long but this only happens to the page I'm trying to type on.

I always thought that if something was in the header/footer area and not actually being worked on then it would be left alone, is this not the case and there is another setting I need to select? Can I fake locking this image? I've googled many different techniques but none of them seem to work. Is there a hack I can do to have this image "layer" remain still?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Will you screenshot what was going on? I want to make sure I understand your description correctly.